# How can I get my own bundle's infomation?

Tags: ios, nsbundle

I want to get some information of "myBundle.bundle" such as version,create time whitch identify the bundle. Thest information may wirite by myself localed in myBundle.bundle.

Are there any recommend method for doing this ?

I try like this, but not success:

1. I put a plist named Info.plist into the root of myBundle.bundle.
2. read the info like below,but the info is nil:

   ```
   self.bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myBundle" ofType:@"bundle"]];
   NSDictionary * info = [self.bundle infoDictionary];
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use the following line of code to get Bundle Version

```
NSString * bundleVersionString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
```

Comment: I didn't want to get the app's version, I want to get myself bundle's version. Are there any iOS recommend methord ? otherwise I should write the info by my way.

Answer (score 0):

NSDictionary *infoDictionary = [[NSBundle mainBundle]infoDictionary];

NSString *build = infoDictionary[(NSString*)kCFBundleVersionKey];

This will give all the info. that is stored in plist like version,bundle version, display name, etc.